# How to use Mmap to share memory. Please correct My code

Tags: c++, unix, mmap

The problem here is that I want the our put to be 93. 
I want the variable to be shared by all threads. Like a static variable is common to all objects I want a variable common to all threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int *glob_var; 

int main(void)
  {
  glob_var = (int*)mmap(NULL, sizeof *glob_var, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  *glob_var = 1;
  int ppid =fork();

  if (ppid == 0) {
     *glob_var = 92;  printf("%d\n", *glob_var);

  } else if(ppid!=0){
     (*glob_var)++; /////I want a 93 over here???
      printf("%d\n", *glob_var); /////I want a 93 over here??? print
      munmap(glob_var, sizeof *glob_var);
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Variables are shared between all threads.  You don't have to do anything to make that happen.

Comment: That's the difference between threads and processes. Processes each have their own memory, threads all run in the same memory. Just use global variables or pass pointers between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Both of processes update `glob_var`. You need to coordinate access to this shared memory. It's required to guarantee proper order of data modification, i.e value `92` should be assigned first.

[Semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html) is often used to synchronize operations in such situations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Binary semaphore implementation. Initial state 0
union semun 
{
  int val;
  struct semid_ds *buf;
  unsigned short int *array;
  struct seminfo *__buf;
};

int binary_semaphore_allocation (key_t key, int sem_flags)
{
  return semget (key, 1, sem_flags);
}

int binary_semaphore_deallocate (int semid)
{
  union semun ignored_argument;
  return semctl (semid, 1, IPC_RMID, ignored_argument);
}

int binary_semaphore_initialize (int semid)
{
  union semun argument;
  unsigned short values[1];
  values[0] = 0;
  argument.array = values;
  return semctl (semid, 0, SETALL, argument);
}

int binary_semaphore_wait (int semid)
{
  struct sembuf operations[1];
  operations[0].sem_num = 0;
  /* Decrement by 1. */
  operations[0].sem_op = -1;
  operations[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
  return semop (semid, operations, 1);
}

int binary_semaphore_post (int semid)
{
  struct sembuf operations[1];
  operations[0].sem_num = 0;
  /* Increment by 1. */
  operations[0].sem_op = 1;
  operations[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
  return semop (semid, operations, 1);
}

int main(void)
{
  key_t ipc_key;
  ipc_key = ftok(".", 'S');
  int sem_id;

  glob_var = (int*)mmap(NULL, sizeof *glob_var, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  *glob_var = 1;

  if ((sem_id=binary_semaphore_allocation(ipc_key, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL)) != -1) 
  {
    if (binary_semaphore_initialize(sem_id) == -1) 
    {
      printf("Semaphore initialization failed");
      return 2;
    }
  }

  int ppid = fork();
  if (ppid == 0)
  {
    if ((sem_id = binary_semaphore_allocation(ipc_key, 0)) == -1) 
    {
      printf("Child process failed to open semaphore");
      return 3;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Wait in parent process until child update glob_var
    binary_semaphore_wait(sem_id);
  }

  if (ppid == 0) 
  {
    *glob_var = 92;  
    printf("%d\n", *glob_var);
    binary_semaphore_post(sem_id);
  }
  else if(ppid!=0)
  {
    (*glob_var)++; 
    printf("%d\n", *glob_var); 
    munmap(glob_var, sizeof *glob_var);
    binary_semaphore_deallocate(sem_id);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
92
93
```